# Adb transfers file with a very slow speed

Tags: android, macos, adb

I'm having a problem with adb on my machine, it runs on OSX Yosemite. I was trying to `adb install` a 44mb apk and it took 5 minutes for the apk to be installed. I try to narrow the problem, and it seems that the `adb push` has something to do with this.

I tested with `adb push -p src dest` to see the transfer progress. The transfer works fine for small files, leaving about 1300KB/s transfer rate. It slows down a lot when transferring large files, about 120KB/s transfer rate. The transfer always slows down at byte 8388608/total.

I've tested adb push with the same device and same USB cable at my coworker's Mac using OSX Yosemite and it works fine. I don't know what causes the problem, could somebody help me?

Comment: did find a solution to this?
I have the exact same problem

Comment: not yet unfortunately

Comment: same here. In my case, it went fast, then stalled.  I cancelled the transfer and restarted it and stated at slow speed from the very start.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Performance Tuning the Network Stack on Mac OS X Part 2](https://rolande.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/performance-tuning-the-network-stack-on-mac-os-x-part-2/),
edit your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file as follows and reboot your machine.

```
kern.ipc.somaxconn=2048
net.inet.tcp.rfc1323=1
net.inet.tcp.win_scale_factor=4
net.inet.tcp.sendspace=1042560
net.inet.tcp.recvspace=1042560
net.inet.tcp.mssdflt=1448
net.inet.tcp.v6mssdflt=1412
net.inet.tcp.msl=15000
net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive=0
net.inet.tcp.delayed_ack=3
net.inet.tcp.slowstart_flightsize=20
net.inet.tcp.local_slowstart_flightsize=9
net.inet.tcp.blackhole=2
net.inet.udp.blackhole=1
net.inet.icmp.icmplim=50
```

I was faced with the same problem and solved it by the above settings.

Comment: Thanks, pushing a 40mb file now takes only 30 seconds instead of 5 minutes.

Comment: too bad this doesn't do anything on 10.12

Comment: Edit my `/etc/sysctl.conf` file of which device? The file does not exist both in my Mac and Android device. MacOS10.13.6 (17G65) / Android 6.0.1

Comment: @pea3nut 
You can create the file in your Mac if it doesn't exist.
Please see `man sysctl.conf`.

Answer (score 6):

I was struggling with this, then saw a suggestion to just start a webserver on the host machine and let your android device/emulator just download the apk.

```
cd build/outputs/apk/
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Then, in the android device I just open a browser to `http://<host_ip>:8000/` - it downloads in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try use Wi-Fi. Probably, your USB cable is slow or your phone doesn't support fast high-speed file transfer. Look: [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp). I had 30-35 mbps, when I sent 2 GB of GTA SA.

If you don't have Wi-Fi, you can use Tethering from Android in computer.

Comment: I don't think the cable is the problem, because the same cables have been tested on another computer and they work just fine. Tried installing via Wi-Fi but it's awfully slow last time I tried, maybe I'll try using a different Wi-Fi network sometime.